# What font has both a checkmark and an N/A?

Tags: fonts

What font has both a checkmark and an N/A ?

I am preparing a single-page summary of work performed, and it would be nice to have both a checkmark and N/A in the same font, because it might be visually pleasing and because I do not want to have to change the font on a cell-by-cell basis.

Answer (score 5):

There are different three Unicode characters for checkmarks: [U+2611](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2611/fontsupport.htm), [U+2713](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/fontsupport.htm) and [U+2714](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2714/fontsupport.htm). Those links contain popular fonts that have them. `Arial Unicode MS` is probably the easiest if you are on Windows; the `DejaVu` family also works well.

`NA` (`n/a`) should be done using normal Latin (English) characters. I'm not aware of a Unicode font glyph for it (`NA`), nor could I find one. Both Arial Unicode MS and the DejaVu family support the Latin (English) alphabet, so they can be typed normally.

Comment: Maybe I can use &empty; instead of N/A. They sort of map.

Comment: If you could provide an example of what the NA should look like, I might be able to find something. HTML `&empty;` is [U+2205](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2205/index.htm). The [no symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol) is [U+20E0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20e0/index.htm). Also, what are you using to generate/view this summary?